# alter custom attribute using css() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
<div data-progress="0"></div>

$('div').css('data-progress',10');
```

why this doesn't work? I'd put this within a loop and manipulate the div's data-progress attr but nothing happened.

Comment: Should that `'` character be there, to the right of the `10`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work because `data-progress` is not a CSS property, it is a custom *attribute*.

Use the [`.attr()` method](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) to modify the attribute.

```
$('div').attr('data-progress', 10);
```

Also, you had a stray `'` after the `10`, remove that.